# Create unique identifier consisting of Year+Month+Number for copied data

Tags: vba, excel

Hi guys with this For each loop I copy data into a summary sheet:

```
For Each sheet_name In Sheets("Frontend").Range("L21:L31")
Set ws = Worksheets(sheet_name.Text)

 For ZeileUntersucht = 20 To 515
    If ws.Cells(ZeileUntersucht, 238).Value = "yes" Then
        Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(ZeileEintragen, 3) = 
ws.Cells(ZeileUntersucht, 1)
        Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(ZeileEintragen, 4) = 
ws.Cells(ZeileUntersucht, 240)
        Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(ZeileEintragen, 6) = 
ws.Cells(ZeileUntersucht, 11)
        Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(ZeileEintragen, 7) = 
ws.Cells(ZeileUntersucht, 10)
        Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(ZeileEintragen, 9) = 
ws.Cells(ZeileUntersucht, 4)
        Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(ZeileEintragen, 2) = ws.Name
        Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(ZeileEintragen, 8) = "EUR"
        Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(ZeileEintragen, 10) = Date + 
Time
        ZeileEintragen = ZeileEintragen + 1


    End If
Next ZeileUntersucht

Next sheet_name
```

I want to add in the first column a unique identifier looking like this
2017510001. So Year+Week+0001 and then counting upwards for each row where there is data.

This is what I have so far:

```
n = 1
For i = 11 To LastRow
    If  Then
     n = n + 1
    End If
 Next i

 txtCount = Format(n, "00")

'Create ID Number'

IDnum = " " & txtYear & "" & txtMonth & "-" & txtCount & ""
```

But I am having issues how to actually input the ID into Column A and to only fill out the rows with data.

If you need further clarification just ask.

Edit: My current function now looks like this:

```
Sub MacroToDoTheWork()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheet_name As Range
Dim txtYear As String
Dim txtWeek As String
Dim txtCount As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim D As Date

'Define Variables 
txtYear = Format(D, "yyyy")
txtWeek = Format(D, "ww")

'Unique Identifier
LastRow = Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(Worksheets("Market Place Output").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    txtCount = Format(i - 1, "0000")
    Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(i, 1).Value = txtYear & txtWeek & txtCount
Next i

End Sub
```

The Output of this is the following identifier:
1899520001 instead of 2017510001

Which leads me to believe that it actually stores the date 31.12.1899 instead of the current date. This is the current issue I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to add this into column A of Worksheets("Market Place Output") then this will do that for you (assumes you have headers, and that txtYear and txtMonth already have some data in them):

```
Sub foo()
LastRow = Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(Worksheets("Market Place Output").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
txtYear = Format(Date, "yyyy")
txtWeek = Format(Date, "ww")
For i = 2 To LastRow
    txtCount = Format(i - 1, "0000")
    Worksheets("Market Place Output").Cells(i, 1).Value = txtYear & txtWeek & txtCount
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: was just able to test this now works as intended! Would there also be a way to display txtWeek instead of month sadly the syntax doesnt seem to be the same. As txtMonth I have : txtMonth = Format(Month(reqDate), "00") Thanks again!

Comment: Of course you can, just make sure that txtWeek is formatted correctly as you have done for the month and it should be as simple as that...

Comment: Thank you you have been very helpful I have my Identifier running in the format I want now the only issue I have is that it doesnt display everything according to todays date but instead 31.12.1899 and I have no idea why it does that...

Comment: I'm not too sure why that's the case, and as I have no sample data to test against, I would be guessing, if you could provide some sample data then I could give you a more educated answer...

Comment: @Tim updated my answer and it works as expected, I'm not sure where you were getting the value for the variable D, but I've amended that to take today's date and it is writing like 2017510001, then 2017510002, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As String
'This would be where your other code sits, including Dim for LastRow
j = 1
For i = 11 To LastRow
    k = Format(j, "0000")
    Cells(i, 1).Value = "'" & txtYear & "" & txtMonth & k
    j = j + 1
    k = ""
Next i
```

I made this match the example you gave, where the output is (for first item today) *2017120001*.